# How to let unison output the results of comparing replicas but not synchronize them

Tags: file, tree, synchronization, unison

I have a question about the file synchronizer, unison. Is there a way to let unison compare  two replicas and output the difference (to the standard output or a file) but not execute any updates?

I could do this by just hitting `/` (skip) for each update possibility in the interactive session, but I have more than a thousand lines of possibilities and lost patience to hold the `/` key for a long time. Is there a way to skip all automatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if this is a practical solution for you, but if you run Unison in text mode (`unison -ui text`), you can get an overview of all content to be transmitted by typing an upper-case `L` at the prompt (when it's ready to reconcile the changes). Perhaps you could automate this using *expect*?

Comment: Thank you for the answer. `L` key looks useful in my case, indeed. Can you tell me about `expect`? Is it an option of unison?

Comment: @norio, no, [expect](https://linux.die.net/man/1/expect) is a traditional Unix utility to automate certain tasks, esp. interactive ones. Unfortunately, I have no experience with it, so maybe you could look up a few examples if you're considering this approach?